# I have a problem after Installing a language update in SharePoint 2013

Tags: error

I can't Acces SharePoint anymore.

Event ID 6398: I'm getting the Following Errors:

> The Execute method of job definition
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.LMTRepopulationJob (ID
>   90e3848e-b299-4aaa-b0b6-4ec9d0135202) threw an exception.

More information is included below.

> Event 8306 (SharePoint Foundation) of severity 'Error' occurred 11
>   more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log
>
> Unknown SQL Exception 15151 occurred. Additional error information
>   from SQL Server is included below.
>
> event: Cannot drop the event session
>   'SharePoint_Diagnostics_e0c6335fd17a480b8bcf6b9fd55f3e22_0', because
>   it does not exist or you do not have permission.
>
> Event: An exception occurred when trying to issue security token: The
>   HTTP service located at
>   //localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc/actas
>   is unavailable.  This could be because the service is too busy or
>   because no endpoint was found listening at the specified address.
>   Please ensure that the address is correct and try accessing the
>   service again later..

Comment: Did you run configuration wizard after installation?